# Given different subspaces of $\Bbb R^4$, $U,W$ and $\dim U=\dim W$; $[(1,1,1,0) , (0,0,1,1)]$ belong to the intersection of U and W.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find $\dim U, \dim U\cap W$, and $\dim(U+W)$.

I know $\dim U$ and $\dim W$ must be bigger than or equal to two, and the same for the intersection. And $\dim U$ and $\dim W$ must be smaller than $4$. Are they $2$ or $3$?

I've spent over 3 hours on this and I cannot for the life of me write a coherent proof.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If the subspaces are distinct, they can *neither have dimension* $4$ nor be *equal to their intersection*, which has dimension $\ge 2$. So, can you say first whether $\dim(U\cap W)=2$ or $3\mkern1mu$?

Comment: Their dimensions cannot be equal to the dimension of the intersection? 

Why is the dimension of the intersection greater than or equal to three? 


I'm sorry... I don't understand. 


If I assume that dimU and dimW are 2 and I assume that dim(U∩W)=2 I can reach a contradiction because that forces without loss of generality for the bases to be proportional, therefore contradicting distinctness.

I'm sorry man, I'm going to need a stronger hint I just don't understand.

Comment: If their dimension is also the dimension of their intersection, $U=U\cap W$ because $U\cap W\subset U$, and if the inclusion is strict, the dimensions can't be equal. Similatly for $W$. Therefore $\dim(U\cap W)<\dim U=\dim W$. I didn't meanay the intersection has dimension $\ge 3$, but $2$ (sorry for the typo!) I just meant whether you can decide between $2$ and $3$.

Comment: The intersection cannot be three right? Becuase then that would mean there exists a vector which is comprised of three linearly independent vectors belonging to the respective subspaces, which would contradict the dimension being two? 


Assuming that^ is true, I than inspected the condition where dimU∩W=2 and said if that were to be true than there is a vector which is comprised of two linearly independant vectors belonging to both subspaces, which means that they have the same base which means they are the same subspace.

Comment: More simply, if the inersection has dimension $3$, $U$ and $W$ have dimension $4$, hence are both equal tp $\Bbb R^4$, and cannot be distinct.

Comment: True...Ok so that disproves the case where the dimensions are equal to two. They can't be 4 so they must be 3....dear mother of god thank you so much :) I think I'm gonna hand it in like this.

Comment: Whose mother?? ;o)